# Construct array of multi-dimensions of class (Unit) is null c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I tried to Construct an array of multi dimensions of class( Unit ) but all array elements defined as null

```
Unit[,] unitsvalue = new Unit[x, y];
```

I want to defined array element as `new Unit();`

Answer (score 2):

`new Unit[x, y];` provides storage for references to elements, but it does not construct the elements themselves. You need to assign them individually in your code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != x ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j != y ; j++)
        unitsvalue[i,j] = new Unit();
```

This works differently for value types: if you make `Unit` a `struct`, you wouldn't need two loops.

Comment: i want an optimize solution ! not 2 for loops

Comment: @salamonti You can do it with a single loop, but there is no way around having to perform (x*y) assignments, unless you make `Unit` a value type.